# How manage data when its already fetched by Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using a database with MySQL and getting it using Axios and a useEffect. Then I pass my database data to a component using a prop. Like this:

```
const Component = () => {
 //DB
  const urlProxy = "/api/cities";

  //Hooks
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  //DB Fetch
  const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(urlProxy)
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      fetchData();
    };
  }, []);


return (
    <>
      <h1>Cities</h1>
      <Cities api={data} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Inside of Cities Component I want to make an algorithm to manipulate that data, but I get one empty array (from const [data, setData] = useState([]). After a moment I get the fetched data from database.

```
const Cities = (api) => {

console.log(data) // First Print: [{api:Array(0)}] then [{api:Array(2)}]

return(
<>
  ...
</>
)

}
```

So if it prints at first an empty array I would get an error

I was thinking of using a useTimeout() but i don't know if there is a better solution, in order to use data after it's fetched.

Comment: Just handle the render before the data comes—that’s the nature of async fetching.

Comment: You can keep track of `loading` as well (whether via a `loading` variable or via the absence of `data`). Then `{loading ? <>loading</> : <Cities api={data} /> }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you would need to do is manipluate the data before you set it into your state

and the best way to wait until that is done is to have a loading state that waits for your data to be pulled and then have your useEffect manipulate it.

Something like this should work for you

```js
const urlProxy = "/api/cities";
const Component = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  //DB Fetch
  const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios
      .get(urlProxy)
      .then((res) => {
        // Manipulate your data here before you set it into state
        const manipluatedData = manipulateData(res.data)
        setData(manipluatedData);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      })
      .finally(() => 
        setLoading(false);
      })
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      fetchData();
    };
  }, []);

if(loading){
   return 'loading....'
}

return (
    <>
      <h1>Cities</h1>
      <Cities api={data} />
    </>
  );
};
```